# Handling customized listview in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-lists

I am developing an app where I am using customized listview. First i will go with code and i will ask my question(at bottom).

Main.java (using adapter class to set data to listview)

```
Myadapter adapter = new Myadapter();
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

custom.xml

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:background="#adadad"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Myadapter class:

```
     public class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return startarr.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = null;
        int i;
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater = getLayoutInflater();
        v = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.custom,null);
        TextView aptdate = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView apttime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView aptname = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView aptid   = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        //Button btn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final String arlstdate[] = startarr.get(position).split("~");
        for (i = 0; i < arlstdate.length; i++) {
            aptdate.setText(arlstdate[i]);

            try {
                // Getting Array of Contacts
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                contacts = json.getJSONArray("schedule");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for(int j = 0; j < contacts.length(); j++){
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(j);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    final String id = c.getString("scheduleId");
                    String startTime = c.getString("startDateTime");
                    String endTime = c.getString("endDateTime");
                    String type = c.getString("scheduleType");

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                        Date startedTime = sdf.parse(startTime);
                        Date endedTime = sdf.parse(endTime);
                        int getstartdate = startedTime.getDate();
                        int getstartmonth = startedTime.getMonth();
                        int getstartyear = startedTime.getYear();
                        int getday = startedTime.getDay();
                        final int getstartingtime = startedTime.getHours();
                        final int getstartingmin = startedTime.getMinutes();
                                                    long diff = endedTime.getTime() - startedTime.getTime();
                        int hours = (int)(diff/(60*60*1000));
                        testselectID = String.valueOf(hours);

                        hoursarray.add(testselectID);
                        starttimearray.add(String.valueOf(getstartingtime+":"+getstartingmin));


                        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTime(startedTime);

                        System.out.println((calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR))+"-"+(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                        if(arlstdate[i].equals((calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR))+"-"+(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))))
                        {
                            aptid.append(id+"\n");
                            apttime.append(testselectID+"Hrs"+"\n");
                            aptname.append((String.valueOf(getstartingtime+":"+getstartingmin))+"\n");

                        }

                }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "schedule error is " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            }

        return v;


 }
    }
```

Here I am appending the data to textviews and output of the following code is ...
   [image]\

Upto here everything works good. But what my question is.....

When i click on custom list view the values need to display in seperate toast message. As i have some idea regarding list view click listener, but here if using that code it is taking last appeneded data details. for example if i click on first one (in image) it is displaying 16:40.not displyaing 12:0. what i want is I need to display two of them differently with different toast message.

Can anyone help me with this....

Comment: share custom.xml (layout) as well

Comment: Just maintain **One Object** per list item and in ListView's `onItemClick()` get that Object with position click.. Don't append string data.. For this you have to make a Custom `List<Object>` and pass it to your adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You make your live very hard yourself in NOT implementing a proper Model. You should parse your Json outside the Adapter and make Java-classes out of these informations. Then pass a List or an Array as data to your Adapter, while returning Model-objects in `getItem(position)`!
This way you flawlessly can implement an `OnItemClickListener` and gather whatever data you want.

You also just completely ignore the `convertView` Parameter. You should take this View instead of inflating a new one if it is NOT null for performance optimization!

Comment: but here why i am following this code is first i am removing duplicate dates from array and checking condition again using and appending data.....

Answer (score 0):

```
for that you have to implement the OnItemClickListener event on listview .

listview.OnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
    // getting values from selected ListItem

       }
   });
 Now you have position of your listview then Whatever the list position that corresponding value is diplays in toast.
```